# keytool error: Alias has no key

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish, x509certificate, keystore

Добрый день!

Возникла проблема. Пытаюсь поменять пароль для alias в keystore.jks, однако сталкиваюсь с ошибкой.

Делаю следующим образом:

```
keytool -keypasswd -keystore keystore.jks -alias <alias_name>
```

Ввожу текущий пароль для keystore:

```
Enter keystore password: <keystore_password>
```

Возникает следующая ошибка:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <alias_name> has no key
```

При этом убедился, что публичный ключ для данного алиаса существует, используя:

```
keytool -list -rfc -keystore keystore.jks -alias <alias_name> -storepass <keystore_password>
```

Выдает:

```
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFuzCCBKOgAwIBAgIQEIkdUdfGxpksmUcK38UpfTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBV
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJDTjEaMBgGA1UEChMRV29TaWduIENBIExpbWl0ZWQxKjAoBgNV
BAMTIVdvU2lnbiBDQSBGcmVlIFNTTCBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZSBHMjAeFw0xNjA4MTYx
MzU5MjlaFw0xOTA4MTYxMzU5MjlaMCExCzAJBgNVBAYTAlJVMRIwEAYDVQQDDAlh
................................................................
................................................................
    ----END CERTIFICATE--------
```

Что это может быть? Не могу найти достаточно полной информации по данной ошибке.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Решил проблему кардинальным способом. Использовал для генерации сертификатов letsencrypt, а затем настроил все по этому алгоритму: https://maximilian-boehm.com/hp2121/Create-a-Java-Keystore-JKS-from-Let-s-Encrypt-Certificates.htm. Тем не менее, хотелось бы знать в чем была проблема топика